# Convergence in law and points of equality

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X_{n}$ be a sequence of real random variables converging in law to $X$. Let us suppose that the cummulative distribution function of $X$ is continuous everywhere. Let $\{a_{n}\}_{n}$ be a sequence of real numbers.

My question is whether or not $\lim_{n}\mathbb{P}(X_{n} = a_{n}) = 0$. I hope so, because $X_{n}$ converges in law to $X$ and $\mathbb{P}(X = a_{n}) = 0$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true. If the conclusion fails then there exists $\epsilon >0$ a subsequence $(n_k)$ such that $P(X_{n_k}=a_{n_k})>\epsilon$ for all $k$.

Suppose $(a_{n_k})$ is bounded. By going to a subsequence we may suppose $a_{n_k}$ tends to some real number $a$. Now $\epsilon <P(a_{n_k}-\frac 1  k <X_{n_k} \leq a_{n_k})\to P(X=a)=0$ (by uniform convergence of $F_{X_n}$), a contradiction.

Now suppose there is a subsequence of  $a_{n_k}$ tending to $+\infty$. (We may write $a_{n_k}$ for the subsequence also, by an abuse of notation). Let $M$ be any positive number. Then,  $P|X_{n_k}| <M) \to P(|X|<M)$ but $P(|X_{n_k}| <M) \leq P(X_{n_k}\neq a_{n_k})$ for $k$ sufficiently large. So we get $ P(|X|<M) \leq 1-\epsilon$. But this cannot hold for all $M$.

The case when $-\infty$ is a limit point of $(a_{n_k})$ is similar.